# How do I set a dynamic width percentage on repeater items?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I've got a repeater using an array of objects as the dataprovider.  For each object, I want to create a label inside a container.  Each container should be the same size even if the label is too long to display.

```
<mx:HBox width="100%">
    <mx:Repeater id="repeater" dataProvider="{objList}"> 
        <mx:Box width="11%" verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="center">
            <mx:Label text="{repeater.currentItem.Text}" width="100%" textAlign="center" truncateToFit="true"/>
        </mx:Box>
    </mx:Repeater>
</mx:HBox>
```

If I know the list has 9 items, I can set the width to 11% and be happy.  But I want to be able to handle a list of 6-15 items.

I've considered setting the width of the box to the result of a function, but the width will not accept a string result.  Returning a number will just set it to that exact width rather than a percentage.

```
<mx:Box width="{GetPercent()}" verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="center">
```

I've also considered looping over the repeater items to set the percentWidth, but it would be preferable to have the width defined before rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I don't have spark, I eventually got this to work by replacing the Box with a Canvas (that had clipContent set to true).  The weird part was that also I had to remove width="100%" from the label (and of course set horizontalCenter to 0).

```
<mx:Repeater id="repeater" dataProvider="{objList}"> 
    <mx:Canvas verticalScrollPolicy="off" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" clipContent="true">
        <mx:Label text="{repeater.currentItem.Text}" horizontalCenter="0" textAlign="center"/>
    </mx:Canvas>
</mx:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0):

With a Spark label you can simply set each label to 100% width and force it to automatically truncate, like this: `<s:Label showTruncationTip="true" maxDisplayedLines="1" width="100%"/>`. Not sure if that works the same with the MX label component. With the Spark components it's important to also set the `maxDisplayedLines` to get truncation working properly.